# get matplotlib scattered 3D points to display colors by product of the 3 arrays

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d

I am very new to python, I have just started learning and using it for my dissertation.

I am trying to produce a 3D scatter graph representing a risk matrix. I have used matplotlib to display the point's locations so far.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

x = np.array([4, 3, 5, 4, 7, 7, 5, 7, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 5, 7, 3, 3, 7, 7, 6, 6])
y = np.array([2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2])
z = np.array([3, 7, 4, 4, 4, 7, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5, 8, 4, 5, 4, 3, 7, 6])


ax.scatter(x, y, z)

ax.set_xlabel('Severity')
ax.set_ylabel('Probability')
ax.set_zlabel('Detectability')

rm3=ax.scatter(x,y,z,c=z, cmap='RdYlGn_r')

cbar=plt.colorbar(rm3)

cbar.set_label("RPN")

plt.xlim(1,10)
plt.ylim(1,10)

plt.show()
```

[image]

However, is there anyway to display the point colors by the product of the 3 axes and assign a colorbar? or is there other way to better display the graph?

Thank you.

Comment: You already  have the color corresponding to `z`, as stated with `c=z` in the scatter plot definition, what does restrain you from using `c=x*y*z`?

Comment: I tried changing z to other values too but I was overthinking and didn't realise it was this easy. Now it works perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
x = np.array([4, 3, 5, 4, 7, 7, 5, 7, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 5, 7, 3, 3, 7, 7, 6, 6])
y = np.array([2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2])
z = np.array([3, 7, 4, 4, 4, 7, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5, 8, 4, 5, 4, 3, 7, 6])


ax.scatter(x, y, z)

ax.set_xlabel('Severity')
ax.set_ylabel('Probability')
ax.set_zlabel('Detectability')
c=x*y*z

rm3=ax.scatter(x,y,z,c=c, cmap='RdYlGn_r')

cbar=plt.colorbar(rm3)

cbar.set_label("RPN")

plt.xlim(1,10)
plt.ylim(1,10)

plt.show()
```

Comment: It worked! I have tried something similar but didn't realise I was this close. Thank you so much!